# CakePHP 3 - Weird Caching Issue

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cakephp-3.0

I'm working on a project that was initially started with the cakephp 3.0 public beta, and has since been updated to the current stable version. For some reason, every single request is being cached for ~2 minutes, even those that specifically disable cache. This is making development absolutely impossible, as debugging code (var_dump, etc.) persists despite code changes.

Running locally on MAMP3 (PHP 5.6)

App.php

```
'Cache' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'path' => CACHE
    ],

    'weather' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'duration' => '+6 hours',
        'path' => CACHE,
    ],

/**
 * Configure the cache used for general framework caching.  Path information,
 * object listings, and translation cache files are stored with this configuration.
 */
    '_cake_core_' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'prefix' => '_cake_core_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
        'serialize' => true,
        'duration' => '+2 seconds',
    ],

/**
 * Configure the cache for model and datasource caches.  This cache configuration
 * is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings in connections.
 */
    '_cake_model_' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'prefix' => '_cake_model_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
        'serialize' => true,
        'duration' => '+2 seconds',
    ],
],
```

env.php (i.e. DOTENV)

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Cache\Cache;

Configure::write('debug', true);
Cache::disable();
```

BaseController.php (superclass)

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->response->disableCache();
    Cache::disable();
}
```

`Cache::Enabled()` is outputting `false` as expected

HTTP Responses have the following headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 01 Jun 2015 19:18:39 GMT
Expires:Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Mon, 01 Jun 2015 19:18:39 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

My tmp/cache/*/ directories are always empty.

Despite all of this changes take two minutes to be reflected in the browser.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds more like a non-CakePHP problem, like for example a caching proxy, or an opcode cache like APC or Optimizer+.

Comment: I believe you are right about it being opcache. Disabled that and it seems to be working fine again. Thanks.